# Rails-undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting error undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass. I need to find id of oidValue.if id is nil for oidValue and i need to search oid2 table for get oidValue.How to check nil here.Below code is i am using.Not working if oidId is nil.

```
   oidId = Oid1.find_by(oid: oidvalue).id.to_s
    if oidId.nil?
      oidId = Oid2.find_by(oid: oidvalue).id.to_s
    end
```

Comment: You could just change this to `oid = Oid1.find_by(oid: oidvalue) || Oid2.find_by(oid: oidvalue)` and then interact with the `oid` object (which could still be `nil`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two examples of how to do it.

```
if Oid1.exists?(oid: oidValue)
  oidId = Oid1.find_by(oid: oidValue).id.to_s
else
  oidId = Oid2.find_by(oid: oidValue).id.to_s
end
```

or on one line:

```
oidId = Oid1.exists?(oid: oidValue) ?
          Oid1.find_by(oid: oidValue).id.to_s : Oid2.find_by(oid: oidValue).id.to_s
```

The important thing here is to keep the context readable.

**Note:** You should always test.

I hope this can help you.

**- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -**

**Edit:** Regarding your comment:

> groupName = OidGroup.where("group_type is NULL AND group_type =(?) ", "Get").pluck(:groupname)
>
> "I am trying this but getting empty values.I want both NULL and Get Values groupnames"

***Note:*** If the query finds no records with those conditions, it will return an empty array. Result: `[]`

When you make the query: `OidGroup.where("group_type is NULL AND group_type =(?) ","Get").pluck(:groupname)`

You get: `SELECT "oid_groups"."groupname" FROM "oid_groups" WHERE (group_type = NULL and group_type = ('Get'))`

I think the correct way is: `OidGroup.where("group_type = ? and group_type = ?", nil, "Get").pluck(:groupname)`

to get: `SELECT "oid_groups"."groupname" FROM "oid_groups" WHERE (group_type = NULL and group_type = 'Get')`

You can see the documentation here: [Method Where](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where)

Comment: One more query i have

Comment: groupName=OidGroup.where("group_type is NULL AND group_type =(?) ","Get").pluck(:groupname)

Comment: i am trying this but getting empty values.I want both NULL and Get Values groupnames

Comment: How to do this? Can you help on this?

Comment: @SubashiniRaja Please check the answer at the bottom, I add my comment there.

Comment: Thanks.SELECT "oid_groups"."groupname" FROM "oid_groups" WHERE (group_type = NULL and group_type = 'Get') .And condition is not working.Or only working.

Comment: only returns Get values only

Comment: SELECT "oid_groups"."groupname" FROM "oid_groups" WHERE (group_type is NULL or group_type = 'Get'). This is returning all values.

Comment: groupName= oid_groups.where("group_type is ? or group_type = ?",nil, "Get").pluck(:groupname)

Comment: This is working. I don't know how OR is fetching both Null and Get data

Comment: @SubashiniRaja Cool!! If you think it worked, a positive vote would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the safe navigation operator, that will return nil if the attribute doesn't exist.

`oidId = Oid1.find_by(oid: oidvalue)&.id`

Comment: not working.I have tried      @oidList= Oid1.where(:oid => oidvalue)
    if @oidList.present?
    oidId = Oid1.find_by(oid: oidvalue).id.to_s 
    else
      Oid2.find_by(oid: oidvalue).id.to_s
    end